# If $\lim_{x \to \infty}f'(x)=+\infty$ then $\lim_{x \to \infty}(f(x)-f(x-1))=+\infty$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=+\infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $f$ be differentiable and let $\lim_{x \to \infty}f'(x)=+\infty$ prove that: 1) $\lim_{x \to \infty}(f(x)-f(x-1))=+\infty$ and 2) $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=+\infty$.

1) I'll prove by contradiction. Let $\lim_{x \to \infty}(f(x)-f(x-1))=a$, where $a$ is from and $\Bbb R$. $\lim_{x \to \infty}(f(x)-f(x-1))=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)-f(x-1)}{x-(x-1)}=\lim_{x \to \infty}f'(c)=a$, where c is from $(x-1,x)$ (mean value theorem). As $x$ goes to infinity so does $c$ i.e. we have that $\lim_{x \to \infty}f'(c)=\lim_{c \to \infty}f'(c)=a$. Which is a contradictition since we have that  $\lim_{x \to \infty}f'(x)=+\infty$ .

2) I will also prove this by contradiction. We have that $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=a$ This is equivalent to $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)-f(x-1)=0$. I use mean value theorem and get $\lim_{x \to \infty}(f(x)-f(x-1))=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)-f(x-1)}{x-(x-1)}=\lim_{x \to \infty}f'(c)=0$, where c is from $(x-1,x)$. As $x$ goes to infinity so does $c$ i.e. we have that $\lim_{x \to \infty}f'(c)=\lim_{c \to \infty}f'(c)=0$. Which is a contractition since we have that  $\lim_{x \to \infty}f'(x)=+\infty$ .

Comment: Item 1) is an easy consequence of the mean value theorem. The only issue is that you need to understand the definition of limit, and your approach here suggests you are not quite there yet. Item 2) is an easy consequence of 1). Again, the only issue is understanding the definitions of the objects involved. (Not just their intuitive meanings, their actual definitions.)

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I don't know why i used contradiction and mean value theorem without realizing that i can use only mean value theorem but anyway for 2) since i have $\lim_{x \to \infty}(f(x)-f(x-1))=\infty$ can i add to that  $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x-1)$ and get $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=\infty + \lim_{x \to \infty}f(x-1)$ (1). I know that $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x-1)$ exists(by that i mean its either infinity or finat value) from the fact that $\lim_{x \to \infty}(f(x)-f(x-1))=\infty$. Hence right hand side of (1) equations is equal to $\infty$ Does this sound correct?

Comment: From the fact that $\lim_{x\to\infty}(f (x)-f (x-1))=\infty $ we cannot conclude that $ f $ itself converges in the extended sense.

Comment: Note that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=a$ is not the converse of $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=\infty$. In other word, your proof is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to prove the statement by contradiction (also notice the issues that the other users pointed out). The fact that:
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}f'(x) = +\infty$$
implies that for any $x> x_0$, $f'(x)\geq N.$ Since by the Lagrange theorem:
$$ f(x)-f(x-1) = f'(\xi),\qquad \xi\in[x-1,x] $$
for any $x>x_0 + 1$ we have:
$$ f(x)-f(x-1) \geq N, $$
but since $N$ is an arbitrarily big number,
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x)-f(x-1) = +\infty.$$
The Lagrange theorem also implies:
$$ f(x_0+y)-f(x_0) = y\cdot f'(\xi) \geq Ny, \qquad \xi\in[x_0,x_0+y], $$
hence
$$ f(x_0+y) \geq f(x_0) + Ny $$
gives:
$$ \lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x) = +\infty.$$

Answer (score 3):

1) is wrong because the converse of having an infinite limit is not just the existence of a finite limit. You could also have no limit at all.

2) Same problem.

Comment: There are additional problems, of course. For instance, $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=a$ is definitely not equivalent to $\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x)-f(x-1))=0$.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo hrm why wouldn't we have $f(x) \to a, x \to \infty \implies (f(x) - f(x-1)) \to 0, x \to \infty$?

Comment: @DanZimm That *implication* is correct, it is the converse that fails.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo right right, nonetheless he doesn't need the converse (but yes taking exactly what he said is incorrect)